# Separating the Digits in an Integer - exercise from Deitel's Java book

Tags: java

Exercise from Deitel's "Java How To Program" 10th edition:

> 2.30 (Separating the Digits in an Integer) Write an application that inputs one number consisting of five digits from the user, separates the number into its individual digits and prints the digits separated from one another by three spaces each. For example, if the user types in the number 42339, the program should print

```
4   2   3   3   9
```

> Assume that the user enters the correct number of digits. What happens when you enter a number with more than five digits? What happens when you enter a number with fewer than five digits?[Hint: It's possible to do this exercise with the techniques you learned in this chapter. You'll need to use both division and reminder operations to "pick off" each digit.]

Could someone explain to me how should I go about "picking off" individual integers using division and reminder operators?

EDIT: control structures (if / else and the like) are not allowed yet, those are explored in future chapters. Variables, arithmetic operators and comparison operators only.

Comment: Hint: It's possible to do this exercise with the techniques you learned in this chapter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You know that the number is 5 digit long.

What about

```
number / 10 000 to retrieve the first digit.
number = reminder
number / 1000 to retrieve the second digit.
number = reminder
number / 100 to retrieve the third digit.
number = reminder
number / 10 to retrieve the fourth digit.
and reminder is the 5th one.
```

Answer (score 2):

> Here is the answer of displaying digit in same order u have enter

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class oddMethod {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Enter start number:");
        int number=getNumber();
        int last=Reverse1stTime(number);
        System.out.println("Digit You Enter:"+last);
    }

    private static int getNumber() {
        Scanner sr = new Scanner(System.in);
        return sr.nextInt();
    }
    private static int Reverse1stTime(int number)
    { int  digit=0;
    int reverse=0;
        while(number>0)
        {
            digit=number%10;
            reverse=reverse*10+digit;
            number=number/10;
        }
       return reverseAgain(reverse);
    }
    private static int reverseAgain(int number)
    { int  digit=0;
        int reverse=0;
        while(number>0)
        {
            digit=number%10;
            System.out.println(digit);

            reverse=(reverse*10+digit);
            number=number/10;
        }
        return reverse;
    }
}
Input 12345
Output 12345
```

Answer (score 1):

my small hint with division  - you can divide by 10 and take a look, what is that operation giving...
More, you have to deduce if you want to learn programming.

Answer (score 1):

I also just started with java and with this book, and this is the code that did the tric for me. Forgive me if i did something strange... :)

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SeparateNumber
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int nr, nr1, nr2, nr3, nr4, nr5;

        System.out.print("Enter a number with 5 digits: ");
        nr = in.nextInt();

        nr1 = nr / 10000;
        nr2 = (nr % 10000) / 1000;
        nr3 = ((nr % 10000) % 1000) / 100;
        nr4 = (((nr % 10000) % 1000) % 100) / 10;
        nr5 = (((nr % 10000) % 1000) % 100) % 10;

        System.out.printf("%d%s%d%s%d%s%d%s%d%n", nr1, " ", nr2, " ", nr3, " ", nr4, " ", nr5);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a new question. You should ask it using the 'Ask Question' button instead of putting this down as an answer.

Comment: Looks like an answer to me.

Comment: My intention was idd to answer. :) I know this is an older question but i thought i would be helpfull for other starters to see a possible full 'solution'. Additionaly i also wanted to know if i did something stupid... :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
import java.util.*;
public class DigitsDisplay
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
        int digit;
        System.out.print("Enter a positive number: ");
        digit = input.nextInt();
        int power = 1;
        while (power <= digit) {
            power *= 10;
        }
        power /= 10;
        while (power > 0) {
            System.out.println(digit/power);
            digit %= power;
            power /= 10;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
String str1 = "";
int a = 12345;
while(a>0)
{
  int b = a%10;
  str1 = str1 + String.valueOf(b+" ");
  a = a/10;
}
StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder(str1);
System.out.println(str.reverse());
```

Answer (score 0):

Below code handles splitting on any int in integer range.

Steps:

1. Convert int to String
2. Convert each character of String to int by using Integer.parseInt
3. Store int digits in int[]
4. Print int[]

Sample code:

```
import java.util.*;

public class SplitDigits{
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Enter number:");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int number = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println("You have entered:"+number);
        String str = String.valueOf(number);
        int length = str.length();
        if ( length > 0){
            int[] digits = new int[length];
            for ( int i=0; i < length; i++){
                digits[i] = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(str.charAt(i)));
            }
            for ( int i=0; i < digits.length; i++){
                System.out.println("Digits:"+digits[i]);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

output:

```
java SplitDigits
Enter number:
123456789
You have entered:123456789
Digits:1
Digits:2
Digits:3
Digits:4
Digits:5
Digits:6
Digits:7
Digits:8
Digits:9
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;  
public class DigitSeparator{  
    public static void main(String[] args){  
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);  
        System.out.print("Enter a 5 digit number: ");  
        int number = input.nextInt();  

        System.out.print((number / 10000)+ "   ");   
        int divider = 10000;  
        int mod = number % 10000;  

        for(int i = 1; i <= 4; i++){  
            divider /= 10;  
            System.out.print( mod/divider +"   ");  
            mod %= divider;         
        }  
        System.out.println();  
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
first import java.util.Scanner; berfore your 
class.
and write this code in your main method.

Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Enter a five digit number: ");
     int number = input.nextInt();
     int first_digit = number / 10000;
     int second_digit = (number % 10000) / 1000 ;
     int third_digit = (number % 1000) / 100;
     int fourth_digit = (number % 100) / 10;
     int fifth_digit = (number % 10);
     System.out.printf("%d   %d   %d   %d   
     %d%n", first_digit, second_digit, third_digit, fourth_digit, fifth_digit);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
package chapter1;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Exercise3 {

    public static void main (String[] args){
    Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.print ("Enter a number that consist of 5 digits: ");
    int num =scan.nextInt();

    int digit1 =num / 10000;
    int digit2 =(( num % 10000) / 1000 );  // the modulus answer of num/10000 is divided by 1000
    int digit3 =( ( num % 1000) / 100 );
    int digit4 = ( ( num% 100 ) / 10 );
    int digit5 = ( num % 10);

    System.out.print (digit1+"\t");
    System.out.print(digit2+"\t");
    System.out.print(digit3+"\t");
    System.out.print(digit4+"\t");
    System.out.println(digit5+"\t");
    }


}
```

Comment: First: Welcome to SO :) Now, please rethink your answer. For once it does not really answer what OP asked: "Could someone explain to me how should I go about(...)" since you don't explain. However if you think your posted code provides an answer, then maybe you could explain why and how? Have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) to see how you could improve your answer. Thanks

Answer (score -2):

Answer is:

```
//your package name

import java.util.Scanner; //for input the userin
public class SeperateDigit {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.printf("Enter a 5 digit number: ");
        int number = input.nextInt();

        int number1 = number/100000;
        int arrange = number%10000;
        int number2 = arrange/1000;
        int number3 = (arrange % 1000) /100;
        int number4 =(( arrange % 1000) % 100) / 10;
        int number5 = ((arrange % 1000) % 100) % 10;

        System.out.printf("%d %d %d %d %d", number1,number2,number3,number4, number5);
    }
}
```

and Result is

```
Enter a 5 digit number: 422339
4 2 3 3 9
```