# Summing a number's digits in Java

Tags: java, math

Let's say you have an integer '75'. Normally, in your head, you can add the '7' with the '5' in order to get '12'. So you split the number '75' into two different numbers 7 and 5 then add them together. That leads to my question, how can you perform that in java? Is there a Math method that does it for you?

Comment: Use the modulus operator and division operator to obtain each digit in the number using a loop and keep on adding them.

Comment: Have a look at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25204481/separating-the-digits-in-an-integer-exercise-from-deitels-java-book/35269214#35269214

Answer (score 1):

You can use plain maths

```
int i = 75;
int a = i / 10; // 7
int b = i % 10; // 5
int c = a + b;  // 12
```

Comment: Wow, I had no idea it was this simple. I just tested this with several numbers of different figures, and it worked. Thanks!

Comment: @LawrenceLelo This only works with 1 and 2 digit numbers but you can use loop for more.

Answer (score 1):

You can use some code like:

```
int num=75;
int sum_digits=0;

while(num>0){
    int digit = num%10;
    num /= 10;
    sum_digits += digit;
}
```