# A Java program that gets an integer, separates the individual digits and gives the sum of the digits

Tags: java

Below is my code, I have been able to get the sum of the digits, but I don't know how to cleanly separate and print the individual digits of my integer. Can it be done within my 'do' loop?

```
import java.util.*;

public class Ch5PgEx1 {

  static Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    int num;
    int sum;
    int remainder;
    int count;

    System.out.print("Please enter an integer: ");
    num = console.nextInt();
    System.out.println();

    sum = 0;
    count = 0;

    do {
        remainder = num % 10;
        sum = sum + remainder;
        num = num / 10;
        count++;
    }
    while (num > 0);


    System.out.print("There are " + count + " digits in your number. \nThe sum of the individual digits is:" + sum);
    System.out.println();
  } 
}
```

Comment: Just print out `remainder` inside the loop? Or do you want to store it in an array?

Comment: "Can it be done within my 'do' loop?" Yes

Comment: Treat it as a smaller problem. Put this code aside for a moment, start a new file with a public main that just has `int v = 1234;` and then think about how you would _only_ split that up in a list of numbers 1, 2, 3, and 4. How many numbers is that supposed to be? Why? How would you find out? These are things that people have already asked before, so you can find the answers to those questions on SO already, but the important part is to make your problem smaller, and tackle that first, then build on that.

Comment: I would want to store it in an array please @UnholySheep

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans i have converted my  integer to a string, ;                                                     
                                                                                                                 
        int num;
        str = Integer.toString(num)                                                                                                         I have the number string now, how do i assign each digit to a character of my string

Comment: What do you know about String? Does it have a way to split itself into individual characters?

Comment: sorry for the late response, i have intermittent internet availability. no offense @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans but you cannot answer questions with more questions. If i had the answer i would not be here. I guess i'm not a logical thinker by nature, I am more of a visual learner, I understand the concepts after going through the answer multiple times not before. But thanks though mate

Comment: I can, though, because the basic rules for posting on SO are [search, and research](/help/how-to-ask): you had a question that you can break down into smaller questions each of which _already have answers on SO_ if you search for them. So as a new question-posting user it is important you're reminded of that. If someone points out that your problem can be reduced to something smaller, then step one is to search whether that smaller thing already has an answer, and if it does: splendid. Your post can be marked as duplicate, or even be deleted because your problem already had a solution.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Separating the Digits in an Integer - exercise from Deitel's Java book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25204481/separating-the-digits-in-an-integer-exercise-from-deitels-java-book)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. To print them just add the print line

   ```
   do {
       remainder = num % 10;
       sum = sum + remainder;
       num = num / 10;
       count++;
       System.out.println(remainder);
   } while (num > 0);

   /*
   Please enter an integer: 123456789

   9
   8
   7
   6
   5
   ...
   ```
2. To store them in an array

   ```
   int[] res = new int[Integer.toString(num).length()];
   do {
       remainder = num % 10;
       sum = sum + remainder;
       num = num / 10;
       res[count++] = remainder;  // LINE 1
   } while (num > 0);

   /*
   Please enter an integer: 123456789

   [9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
   ...
   ```

   To have the array in `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]` way :

   - way change `LINE 1` to `res[res.length - ++count] = remainder;`

Comment: sorry for the late response, i have intermittent internet availability. Your way is the closest i have gotten to printing the number. Thank you m'lord

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure if this would be something you'd be looking for. It does simplifies your code and it builds the array based on the remainders:

### Integer Array

```
int arraySize = String.valueOf(num).length();
List<Integer> collectList = IntStream.range(0, arraySize).map(i -> (int) (num / Math.pow(10, i) % 10)).boxed()
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
Integer[] collect = collectList.toArray(new Integer[0]);

System.out.print("There are " + collectList.size()
        + " digits in your number. \nThe sum of the individual digits is:" + collectList.stream()
        .reduce(Integer::sum).orElse(0));
System.out.println();
```

### Character Array

And if you want with characters, maybe this would also help you:

```
int arraySize = String.valueOf(num).length();
List<Integer> collectList = IntStream.range(0, arraySize).map(i -> (int) (num / Math.pow(10, i) % 10)).boxed()
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
Character[] collect = collectList.stream().map(number -> String.valueOf(number).charAt(0))
        .toArray(Character[]::new);

System.out.print("There are " + collectList.size()
        + " digits in your number. \nThe sum of the individual digits is:" + collectList.stream()
        .reduce(Integer::sum).orElse(0));
System.out.println();
```

Comment: sorry for the late response, i have intermittent internet availability. i am yet to get the concepts above, but i will get there. Thanks mate

Answer (score 0):

Well, I have made a quick example for you. Take a look at it.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Pleaseee, input your numbers.");
        String text = scanner.nextLine();

        int[] arrayOfNumbers = new int[text.length()];

        for (int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++) {
            arrayOfNumbers[i] = text.charAt(i) - '0';
        }
        /*
        // prints every number
        for( int number : arrayOfNumbers){
            System.out.printf(" %s ",number);
        }
        */
        // sums every number
        int sumOfNumbers = IntStream.of(arrayOfNumbers).sum();

        String listOfNumbers = IntStream.of(arrayOfNumbers).mapToObj(Integer::toString).collect(Collectors.joining(", "));

        System.out.printf("Ho-ho-ho! List of numbers is: %s \n", listOfNumbers);
        System.out.printf("Ho-ho-ho! The sum of your numbers is: %d \n", sumOfNumbers);

    }
```

Comment: sorry for the late response, i have intermittent internet availability. There are a few concepts in your answer i have yet to get to and understand. Thanks though mate